# Accessing outlook message body with excel vba: error 287

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

We have a lot of emails saved to a folder on the file system to be processed by extracting text from the message bodies.  Office 2010.

```
Dim app As Object
Dim msg As Object
dim msg_body as string

Set app = New Outlook.Application
Set msg = app.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\path\to\message.msg")

msg_body = msg.body
```

This code works fine on my laptop however when I use it on the work network it gives error '287'.

While debugging I noticed that I can view msg `msg.display` and even change the body with `msg.body = "some text"`.  However I cannot read the message body.  Also tried `msg.HTMLbody` which could not be read.

Comment: Is the failing code exactly the same?  If not, how is it different?

Comment: Exactly the same - the difference is that it is on the work network instead of my laptop (which is not connected to the network).  We are guessing it might be due to vba trying to look up the network address book and having permission problems - however we don't know how to turn off this behaviour (if it is responsible).

Comment: Does that happen for a particular MSG file only? Or all of them?

Comment: All of them.  Even created test email with the word `test` and nothing else and it still didn't work.  Although I could set the `msg.body = "test"` and that worked - it is strange I could write but not read, given that `msg.display` works!

Comment: Code works fine in my network environment, able to read and change message body, tested both unicode and non-unicode message. Though I used `Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` rather than Early binding.

Comment: Tried late binding and also doesn't work - there must be something about our network.  Was thinking to save the message as text and then parse it however SaveAs also doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is your company's policies.
Check this registry key to solve the SaveAs (change the 16 to your office version). 
hkcu\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security\promptoomsaveas

You can change the value to 2, or ask your system administrator to create a new GPO.

More information on this and other security configurations in:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/926512/information-for-administrators-about-e-mail-security-settings-in-outlo