Run-time error '287' Application-defined error in Excel VBA when using Recipients.Add method when creating a TaskItem
I am looking to create tasks in Outlook from an Excel tracker file. I receive

Run-time error '287' Application-defined error

when I try to add the recipient using the Recipients.Add method. As far as I can see, I have defined everything and have included the Outlook library.
Any help, gratefully received!
Sub AssignTaskInOutlook()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient

Dim RecipientName As String
Dim TempVL

TempVL = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Value, Sheets("Settings").Range("EmailLookup"), 2, False)

If WorksheetFunction.IsErr(TempVL) Then
    MsgBox "Error in finding name", vbOKOnly
    End
Else
    RecipientName = TempVL
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add(RecipientName)
    myRecipient.Resolve

    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        With OutTask
            .Subject = "Ensono/Tesco Tracker: " & ActiveSheet.Name & ". "
            If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "" Then
                .Subject = .Subject & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                .Body = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
            Else
                .Subject = .Subject & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
            End If
            .StartDate = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
            .Assign
            .Display
        End With
    End If
    Set OutTask = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End If
End Sub


What is the value of RecipientName at the time of error. Put a breakpoint and check it.

Also please... please... pretty please... do not use End to stop the code as it has several undesirable effects that can lead to unintended consequences. Incorrect Unloading of Global Variables and Objects, memory leaks, Bypassing Error Handling etc are few of those...

Why not add therecipient after checking myRecipient.Resolved?

There are stricter controls when accessing Outlook from other applications. See if you can apply something similar to answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204574/run-time-error-287-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-while-using and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397966/accessing-outlook-message-body-with-excel-vba-error-287
