Excel VBA - run-time error 287: error using olApt.Recipients.Add to create appointment
I had a VBA that created an appointment from an excel information but since the Windows 11 update I'm getting an error when I try to add the recipients. The code runs without issues if I exclude the section where I want to add the recipients of the appointment. So I wonder if the way to write the code changed after the Windows 11 update.
Specifically, the error is in the following line:
     Set recipient = olApt.Recipients.Add(contactEmail)

I'm adding the code below as I have no errors if I run it without adding the recipients.
     ' Create new Outlook application object
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Create a new appointment item
    Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(1) ' 1 represents olAppointmentItem
    
    ' Set properties of the appointment item
    With olApt
        .Subject = "Text "  ' Set the subject of the appointment
        .AllDayEvent = False
        .Start = reminderDate + TimeSerial(7, 30, 0) ' Set the start time of the appointment (one hour from now)
        '.End = contractDate + 1
        .Duration = 15 ' Set the duration of the appointment (in minutes)
        .ReminderSet = False ' Set a reminder for the appointment
        .Body = "Text" ' Set the body of the appointment
    End With
    
    
    ' Add attendees to the appointment
     Set recipient = olApt.Recipients.Add("contactEmail@mail.com")
     recipient.Type = 1 ' 1 represents olRequired


What is recipient declared as?

I found this error can appear if contactEmail is not resolved. Check for this.

@rotabor email address always resolves. Test with the non-existent "contactEmail@mail.com".

There are stricter controls when accessing Outlook from other applications. See if you can apply something similar to answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204574/run-time-error-287-application-defined-or-object-defined-error-while-using and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397966/accessing-outlook-message-body-with-excel-vba-error-287
